# DataAnnotatons with EF and DataBaseFirst not working

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I've modified the code in my model (which is on a separate tier) with metadata hoping this will resolve the issue, but it didn't. It's as if the DataAnnotations from the model are not being picked up? Why???

When viewing the page source, I should be seeing something like the following:

```
data-val-required="The User name field is required."
```

However, all I see is the fiollowing:

```
<div class="editor-label">




            <label for="Email">Email</label>




        </div>




        <div class="editor-field">




            <input id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />




            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>




        </div>
```

When looking at the model for standard account log in, I have the following:

```
YeagerTech.Models.LogOnModel
```

The above is defined in the following Models folder on the root of the website inside the AccountModels.cs file:

```
public class LogOnModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

The above (while the model is on the website front end and not in another tier) works fine and has the required attributes set up in the page source fine.What do I need to do to in order to perform data validation with the EF DataBaseFirst method where my model resides on another tier?
My web.config file is set up as follows:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

On the front-end, I have my view set up as follows:

```
@model YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Customer";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Customer", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Create was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Customer</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
```

The definition for YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer is set up as follows (inside the Reference.cs file)

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]     [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]     [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Customer", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/YeagerTechModel")]     [System.SerializableAttribute()]     public partial class Customer : YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.CustomerDA {     }
```

My model is setup as follows inside the above service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace YeagerTechModel
{
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    [MetadataType(typeof(CustomerDA))]
    public partial class Customer : CustomerDA
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            this.Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class CustomerDA 
    {  
        [DataMember]
        public short CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

Base DbContext class

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace YeagerTechModel
{
    public partial class YeagerTechEntities : DbContext
    {
        public YeagerTechEntities()
            : base("name=YeagerTechEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your entire View look like? Can we see that?
From what I can tell, you do have Email with the Required attribute so, it should be showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I see from your code that you included the `jquery.validate.js` script and the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js script`. However, I do not see that the `jquery` script was included. You must include jquery, and it must be the first script. In addition, since you are using MVC's Ajax capabilities, you also need to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script as well.

Comment: Nope... That didn't do it. I have the below code and still got the same thing meaning the "ModelState.IsValid = true". This is really getting old now...

Comment: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>